# C++ String Array search outputs for every item

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compare

I know it's somewhat confusing this title of question but I really need help. 
I need to find a string in array with many strings. If the string is not found then the appropriate message is showed. However when I use for loop, it then shows this message for every string in array which is not found although it also shows found string... I hope you understand what I mean and sorry if i'm not making sense. here's my code:

```
void Store::search() {
        string name;
        cout << "Enter name of product you're searching: " << endl;
        getline(cin, name);

        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            if (name.compare(database[i].name) == 0){                           
            cout << "-------------<Product found!>-------------" << endl;
            cout << "name: " << database[i].name << endl;
            cout << "supplier: " << database[i].supplier << endl;
            cout << "available quantity: " << database[i].quantity<< endl;
            cout << "price per unit: " << database[i].price<< endl;
            cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
                }
            else
            {
                cout << "Product doesn't exist in database!" << endl;
            }
          }     

        }
```

The code works for searching but how do I stop the output "Product doesn't exist in database!" for every item in array that is not found(even when searched item is found)?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Just remove `cout << "Product doesn't exist in database!" << endl;`?

Comment: Help us help you, please provide a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I know it's confusing and I'm sorry for that but my code is not in english language so I had to change names of variables and everything to post this so it's hard to rewrite everything :/ Basically is there a way to show either "product found" or "Product doesn't exist in database!". So when it founds entered name it doesn't also output for other items not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:
 1. keep a bool variable to be set to true if the item is found in the for loop
 2. add a `break` to immediately exit for loop when item is found
 3. remove the else part, because it will print out "Product doesn't exist in database!" for each loop cycle if the item does not match
 4. after the for loop, check if `found` is false to check if item does not exist in collection

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
{
    if (name.compare(database[i].name) == 0)
    {
        cout << "-------------<Product found!>-------------" << endl;
        cout << "name: " << database[i].name << endl;
        cout << "supplier: " << database[i].supplier << endl;
        cout << "available quantity: " << database[i].quantity<< endl;
        cout << "price per unit: " << database[i].price<< endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
        found = true; // set "found" to true
        break; // add a break to immediately exit for loop when item is found
    }
  }
if (!found)
{
    cout << "Product doesn't exist in database!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very very much kind sir! I have smashed my head for so long instead to go immediately here to ask. Again, thank You very very much! Cheers!

Comment: Glad I helped you, but because yours is really a very beginner level question, I suggest you to study more the C++ programming language (plenty of books and online tutorials/courses for beginners) before asking this kind of questions here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I understand and I intend to! Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

You can use statement flag:

```
void Store::search() 
{
    string name;
    bool found = false
    cout << "Enter name of product you're searching: " << endl;
    getline(cin, name);

    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) 
    {
        if (name.compare(database[i].name) == 0){                           
        cout << "-------------<Product found!>-------------" << endl;
        cout << "name: " << database[i].name << endl;
        cout << "supplier: " << database[i].supplier << endl;
        cout << "available quantity: " << database[i].quantity<< endl;
        cout << "price per unit: " << database[i].price<< endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
        found = true;
        break;
    }

    if (!found)
       cout << "Product doesn't exist in database!" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), which will make your code look something like:

```
auto it = std::find_if(databases.begin(), databases.end(), [&name](const auto &database) {return name.compare(database.name) == 0; });
if (it != databases.end())
{
    cout << it->name << endl;
    cout << "found" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```

Generally speaking, C++ offers many such features that more often than not will make your code shorter, improve readability and guarantee functionality

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to search a product in the database and print its details if found. Otherwise you want to notify user that the product was not found. If I understood you correctly, then you need to move the else statement out of 'for' loop, e.g.:

```
void Store::search() {
    string name;
    cout << "Enter name of product you're searching: " << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        if (name.compare(database[i].name) == 0){                           
        cout << "-------------<Product found!>-------------" << endl;
        cout << "name: " << database[i].name << endl;
        cout << "supplier: " << database[i].supplier << endl;
        cout << "available quantity: " << database[i].quantity<< endl;
        cout << "price per unit: " << database[i].price<< endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
        found = true;
        break;
        }
    }     
    if (!found)
    {
        cout << "Product doesn't exist in database!" << endl;
    }
}
```

If your database may contain more products with the same name, remove 'break;' statement.

Answer (score 0):

A more "modern C++" approach is to leverage the C++ algorithms (such as [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if)), [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and maybe the [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) specifier.

As example (assuming database is a std::vector or some kind of STL container):

```
auto it = std::find_if(database.begin(), database.end(), [&name](const auto& item) { return name.compare(item.name) == 0; });
if (it != database.end())
{
    cout << it->name << endl;
    cout << "found" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```